# Java script uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a Wordpress site where I use Facebook login. it works great apart from on one page:

http://www.wheretotravelblog.com/add-post/

On that page, I see a Java error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentStyle' of null plupload.js:2
g.getStyle plupload.js:2
(anonymous function) plupload.html5.js:1
g.extend.trigger plupload.js:2
(anonymous function) plupload.js:2
j.runtimes.Html5.j.addRuntime.init plupload.html5.js:1
v plupload.js:2
g.extend.init plupload.js:2
WPUF_Obj.featImgUploader wpuf.js:108
WPUF_Obj.init wpuf.js:14
(anonymous function) wpuf.js:213
l jquery.js:2
c.fireWith jquery.js:2
v.extend.ready jquery.js:2
A
```

And the Facebook Login button does not work properly - instead of logging me in, it does nothing.

I looked in the .js file for the code which has a call to the below on line 108

```
WPUF_Obj.featImgUloader
```

And this is what I found:

```
featImgUploader: function() {
        if(typeof plupload === 'undefined') {
            return;
        }

        if(wpuf.featEnabled !== '1') {
            return;
        }

        var uploader = new plupload.Uploader(wpuf.plupload);

        uploader.bind('Init', function(up, params) {
            //$('#cpm-upload-filelist').html("<div>Current runtime: " + params.runtime + "</div>");
            });

        $('#wpuf-ft-upload-pickfiles').click(function(e) {
            uploader.start();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        uploader.init();
```

Anyone got any ideas as to what is causing this issue and if it could be affecting my Facebook login? I think that Facebook also has a call to something .init() so I'm wondering if there is a conflict?

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Answer (score 1):

That's a JavaScript error, not a Java one.
And your plugin seems to be at fault.